# Laravel ACL Kodeine permission slug function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Entrust before to control ACL in Laravel when my project is still Laravel 4, and now with Laravel 5.2 Entrust no longer work, especialy in route filtering.

And then I find this package and trying to use it, but still got a lot of question, so to make it more simple I will explain my use case when I use entrust:

First I want to make a permission for create, view, update and delete for article, in Entrust I will create permission like create_article, view_article, update_article and delete_article.
But now in Kodeine when I create permission there is "slug" so I tried to do this like in documentation say

```
 $permUser = $permission->create([ 
        'name'        => 'article',
        'slug'        => [          // pass an array of permissions.
            'create'     => true,
            'view'       => true,
            'update'     => true,
            'delete'     => true
        ],
        'description' => 'Manange article'
    ]);
```

So from what I read it will be just grouping all of my article permission into one place and there is slug with each parameters view, create, update, delete.

The problem I see is, if I want to make my users to only can view article, how to do that based on permission that I created up there?

Since from documentation the to assignPermission is only give permission name and that mean it will include all slug in there and it will be all true?

So if I want to make users only can view article I need to create something like

```
 $permUser = $permission->create([ 
        'name'        => 'article_view',
        'slug'        => [          // pass an array of permissions.
            'view'       => true,
        ],
        'description' => 'view article'
    ]);
```

And if I want to make users only can create article then I will mean I need to create

```
 $permUser = $permission->create([ 
        'name'        => 'article_create',
        'slug'        => [          // pass an array of permissions.
            'create'     => true,
        ],
        'description' => 'create article'
    ]);
```

then what's the point of slug - is it just pretty much the same like role but with parameter in slug?

Comment: I've repaired a lot of case errors in this question (and I notice the same problem with your answer). Since posts here are for the benefit of readers in the long term, we would appreciate it if more effort was expended on writing. If you are writing from a mobile phone, please still use sentence case when composing your questions and answers - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in your github issue, I suggest you to keep all your article permissions as you alredy have it, in one big group but all of them set to false (keep in mind that you may need to change your 'most_permissive_wins' variable in your acl config file). You can create a "child" group permission for your users role using [Inheritance](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/wiki/Permissions-Inheritance), setting to true all of those permissions your users need. You can then asign that child group to your users role (not the big one) and the user role tou your specific user. To clarify my answer, lets say you have this group:

```
$permArticles = $permission->create([ 
        'name'        => 'articles',
        'slug'        => [          // pass an array of permissions.
            'create'     => false,
            'view'       => false,
            'update'     => false,
            'delete'     => false,
        ],
        'description' => 'All articles module permissions'
    ]);
```

then you can create something like:

```
$articlesPermUser = Permission::create([
            'name'        => 'articles.user',
            'slug'        => [ // an array of permissions only for student
                'view' => true,
            ],
            // we use permission inheriting.
            'inherit_id' => $permArticles->getKey(),
            'description' => 'user articles permissions'
        ]);
```

then you assign your new permission to your user role (I am assuming you alredy have a role name 'user'):

```
$userRole = Role::where('slug', 'user')->first();
$userRole->assignPermission('articles.user');
```

And finally you assign that role to... let say your logged user:

```
Auth::user()->assignRole($userRole);
```

You can also solve this problem by overwriting the permission, this could be done assigning a specific permission value to a user (but yes, you would need to do this for every single user in your app if needed, so I dont like this solution at all).

Lets say we keep our big group:

```
$permArticles = $permission->create([ 
            'name'        => 'articles',
            'slug'        => [          // pass an array of permissions.
                'create'     => false,
                'view'       => false,
                'update'     => false,
                'delete'     => false,
            ],
            'description' => 'All articles module permissions'
        ]);
```

As this group says, any rol with your article permission assgined will not be able to do anything in your articles module. Lets say your user role alredy has this permission, but you want a certain user (lets say the logged one) be able to update an article. You can set the specific update permission value to true like so:

```
Auth::user()->addPermission('update.articles', true);
//or
Auth::user()->addPermission('articles', [
     'update' => true, 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer but over the time, I already find a perfect solution that match what I need. It is not much different from what I do in entrust.

So first I will just create a permission like this for view article

```
$class = 'article';
$permission = new Kodeine\Acl\Models\Eloquent\Permission();
$permUser = $permission->create([ 
    'name'        => $class.'_view',
    'slug'        => [ 
        'view' => true,
    ],
    'description' => 'View '.$class
]);
```

and then another one for example create article

```
$class = 'article';
$permission = new Kodeine\Acl\Models\Eloquent\Permission();
$permUser = $permission->create([ 
    'name'        => $class.'_create',
    'slug'        => [ 
        'create' => true,
    ],
    'description' => 'Create '.$class
]);
```

and later just assign those permission to user role, for example I want to make this user role to be can view article

```
$roleAdmin = Kodeine\Acl\Models\Eloquent\Role::where('name','=','user_1');
$roleAdmin->assignPermission('article_view');
```

I still don't understand about Inheritance feature, and I needed to do this quickly. It maybe not an ideal way, but it's works for me.

Comment: Any solution that fit your needs is welcome when your project deadline is pretty near. Greetings!